# How to interpret multiple writes from many nodes connected to one socket in C

Tags: c, unix, parallel-processing

I am trying to break a work load up to 3 different computers to speed up the computation of it in C using sockets. I am able to connect 3 nodes to one head server and give them the work and compute it. The issue is I am using one read from a data structure, read(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result)), on my head server so the input comes back all in one giant line when I need to be able to add together the inputs. Am I missing something and need to create a new sockfd for each node or is there an easier way to add together the input coming back from the compute nodes? Run the code which will open the server to listen for incoming clients. Once 3 clients connect it will send a write automatically and each will beginning solving how many primes are in the range passed to it. It will return an int of how many primes are in the range on the head server with no spaces. For example 239872209818283. When I want to get 23,987 22,098 18,283

Thanks, below is the code from the head server

```
write(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));//sends the structure back to client
   read(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));
   printf("%d", result.numPrime);
```

Below is the code from the compute node

```
read(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));
   printf("Start: %d, End: %d", result.min, result.max);
   int primeNum = numPrime(result.min, result.max);
   write(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));
```

Head server code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 

#define MAX 257 
#define PORT 9457 
#define SA struct sockaddr

//The struct to be used:
typedef struct results {
int min;
int max;
int numPrime;
} results;

int setupServerSocket(int portno);//setup a server socket   

int callServer(char *host, int portno);//connect to a server
//accept connections on a server socket, return the id of the new socket

int serverSocketAccept(int serverSocket);

void writeInt(int x, int socket);//write an int over the given socket

int readInt(int socket); //read an int from the given socket


    int len; 

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

// Function for calculating prime number between multiple nodes 
void func(int sockfd, int min, int max) 
{

    results result;

    result.min = min;
    result.max = max;
    result.numPrime = 0;

        write(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));//sends the structure back to client 

    read(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));

    printf("%d", result.numPrime);


}  
// Driver function 
int main() 
{ 
    int connfd[3];
    int sockfd;


    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = setupServerSocket(PORT); 
    //assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

   // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
  if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) { 
        printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    // Now server is ready to listen and verification 
    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) { 
        printf("Listen failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n"); 
    len = sizeof(cli); 

    // Accept the data packet from client and verification 
    //connfd = accept(sockfd[0], (SA*)&cli, &len); 



     int i = 0;

     while(i < 3){

          while((connfd[i] = serverSocketAccept(sockfd)) < 0){}

        printf("server acccept the client %d...\n", i); 

    i++;
     }

    // Function for chatting between client and server 
    func(connfd[0], 1000, 334000); 
    func(connfd[1], 334000, 667000);
    func(connfd[2], 667000, 1000000);

    // After chatting close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}




int serverSocketAccept(int serverSocket){

    return accept(serverSocket, (SA*)&cli, &len);

}


 int setupServerSocket(int portno){

    int sockID;


    sockID = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockID == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 



    return sockID;
}
```

Compute node code

```
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#define MAX 257 
#define PORT 9457 
#define SA struct sockaddr

//The struct to be used:
typedef struct results {
int min;
int max;
int numPrime;
} results;


results result;
int findPrime(int); 

int numPrime(int firstInt, int secondInt);
int findPrime(int numInput);

void writeInt(int x, int socket);//write an int over the given socket

void func(int sockfd){ 



    //write(sockfd, result.min, sizeof(test));


    read(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));

    printf("Start: %d, End: %d", result.min, result.max);

    int primeNum = numPrime(result.min, result.max);

    writeInt(primeNum, sockfd);
    //write(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));


} 

int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, connfd; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

    // socket create and varification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.35.195.47"); // thing1 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // connect the client socket to server socket 
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) { 
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n"); 

    // function for chat 
    func(sockfd); 

    // close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}


void writeInt(int x, int socket){

    result.numPrime = x;
    write(socket, &result, sizeof(result));

}

int findPrime(int numInput){

    int i = 2; //declaration of variables 
    int j = 1;
    int isPrime = 1;
    int isNotPrime = 0;

    while(i < numInput && j != 0){

        j = (numInput % i);

        i++;
    }


    if(j == 1){

        return isPrime;
    }

    else{
        return isNotPrime;
    }
}


int numPrime(int firstInt, int secondInt){

    int count = 0;

    for(int i = firstInt; i < secondInt; i++){

        if(findPrime(i)){
            count++;
        }   
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the input, expected result and actual result. It is very difficult to debug/understand incomplete code.

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: Thanks. But you still have not provided input, expected result and actual result. Because descriptions like this "on my head server so the input comes back all in one giant line when I need to be able to add together the inputs" are not very clear. We need the exact code, and the exact behaviour descriptions so that there is no chance of misrepresentations.

Comment: Your `struct result` values are small — 12 bytes. That's well within the MTU, so as long as the head server node writes a result in one call to write, that should be readable as a single unit. Conversely, when the compute nodes write a result unit, the head server node can read single results and it shouldn't be mixed up. However, I'm not sure how you're going to have one socket writing to 3 separate machines unless it is a broadcast socket — and I see no evidence of broadcast communications. And if you do broadcast, all the compute nodes get the same messages. You need three sockets, I think.

Comment: It's still quite unclear your problem is. `printf("%d", result.numPrime);` That will result in all the numbers being printed one after another without any spaces. Add a space after `%d` if that's the problem.

Comment: After some testing I became aware of this issue and was able to change the return type on the func function and return an int. Then from there I was able to return the individual values and add them together and print them one by one.